# how to load image as base layer for further drawing in openlayer 3

Tags: openlayers-3

How to load selected image as base layer for further features like point/polygon/shape to draw onto it. Most of the examples shown on openlayer website, are using "ol.source.OSM" for as base layer source. I don't want to use the OSM as based layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of loading custom images can be found in the Openlayers site, under [Image Load Event](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-load-events.html).

You have to take care about the format of the picture you want to load. As you didn't provide more information, I will use a single, untiled image from a WMS server.

The following snippet is the part of the code which should help you.

```js
var map = new ol.Map( {
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Image( {
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS( {
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {
          'LAYERS': 'topp:states'
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      } )
    } )
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View( {
    center: [-10997148, 4569099],
    zoom: 4
  } )
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```